# Python - How to save output from loop to multiple callable variables

Tags: python, xml, for-loop, parsing

I have the following Python code where **items** is a string of joined XML data produced from two website requests/responses:

```
items = ET.fromstring(new)
for item in list(items):
    url = item.find("url")
    endpoint = url.text
    ##
    resp = item.find("response")
    response = resp.text
    responses = response.split("\n")
    index = responses.index('')
    indexed = responses[:index]
    print(endpoint, *indexed, sep = "\n")
```

which prints:

```
https://www.youtube.com/sw.js_data
HTTP/2 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 17:59:34 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="response.bin"; filename*=UTF-8''response.bin
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy-Report-Only: same-origin; report-to="ATmXEA_XZXH6CdbrmjUzyTbVgxu22C8KYH7NsxKbRt94"
Permissions-Policy: ch-ua-arch=*, ch-ua-bitness=*, ch-ua-full-version=*, ch-ua-full-version-list=*, ch-ua-model=*, ch-ua-platform=*, ch-ua-platform-version=*
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version
Server: ESF
X-Xss-Protection: 0
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
https://www.google.com/client_204?&atyp=i&biw=1440&bih=849&dpr=1.5&ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ
HTTP/2 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
Bfcache-Opt-In: unload
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 17:59:10 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 0
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2022-03-14-17; expires=Wed, 13-Apr-2022 17:59:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; SameSite=none
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
```

Basically, I would like to be able to individually evaluate the data that is produced from the above code to where I could check to ensure header values are in *each* response from the websites. So in this example, the code would check the set of headers produced from the first website first (youtube) and say, all headers look good. Then check the set of headers produced from the second website (google) and say, missing Strict-Transport-Security header (for example). The goal of this code is that it would be able to run validate through these website responses no matter how many are loaded into the initial string and tell me if any headers are missing.

Is there an easy way to do this? I would think at some point each output (list of headers) from each website would be saved to variables that can be referenced/called? Maybe this is getting messy and will not be easy to do - not sure! Also happy to take any advice on making this code a little bit cleaner if there's a more efficient way to do what I am trying to do.

Thank you!

Full XML string below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<items burpVersion="2022.2.3" exportTime="Mon Mar 14 14:28:18 EDT 2022">
  <item>
    <time>Mon Mar 14 13:59:37 EDT 2022</time>
    <url>https://www.youtube.com/sw.js_data</url>
    <host ip="142.250.190.142">www.youtube.com</host>
    <port>443</port>
    <protocol>https</protocol>
    <method>GET</method>
    <path>/sw.js_data</path>
    <extension>null</extension>
    <request base64="false">GET /sw.js_data HTTP/2
Host: www.youtube.com
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.youtube.com/sw.js
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

</request>
    <status>200</status>
    <responselength>3524</responselength>
    <mimetype>JSON</mimetype>
    <response base64="false">HTTP/2 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 17:59:34 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="response.bin"; filename*=UTF-8''response.bin
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy-Report-Only: same-origin; report-to="ATmXEA_XZXH6CdbrmjUzyTbVgxu22C8KYH7NsxKbRt94"
Permissions-Policy: ch-ua-arch=*, ch-ua-bitness=*, ch-ua-full-version=*, ch-ua-full-version-list=*, ch-ua-model=*, ch-ua-platform=*, ch-ua-platform-version=*
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version
Server: ESF
X-Xss-Protection: 0
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

)]}'

[["yt.sw.adr",null,[[["en","US","US","75.188.116.252",null,null,1,null,[],null,null,"","",null,null,"","QUFFLUhqbnREclEzblJmc25GVF9XSXQ1dFZQSm9sRGlmQXxBQ3Jtc0tuU3huS1RoOHQyaFlqN0dLdm4wcGMweXp0OURWQU5RbEJKRko1TlhGYjBoZ3N1Nnpla3QxUFRkN19uaWxoQVZTV0FRUGh0cUw2ckRWbmh5bGhxYkRjNFc2cUREbjB4MnFxMEpval9HUXNZeWU5d1Ztaw\u003d\u003d","CgtaVS1FWnl4ZTJEZyiGhb6RBg%3D%3D"],"Vf114d778||"]]</response>
    <comment />
  </item>
  <item>
    <time>Mon Mar 14 13:59:14 EDT 2022</time>
    <url>https://www.google.com/client_204?&amp;atyp=i&amp;biw=1440&amp;bih=849&amp;dpr=1.5&amp;ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ</url>
    <host ip="172.217.4.36">www.google.com</host>
    <port>443</port>
    <protocol>https</protocol>
    <method>GET</method>
    <path>/client_204?&amp;atyp=i&amp;biw=1440&amp;bih=849&amp;dpr=1.5&amp;ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ</path>
    <extension>null</extension>
    <request base64="false">GET /client_204?&amp;atyp=i&amp;biw=1440&amp;bih=849&amp;dpr=1.5&amp;ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ HTTP/2
Host: www.google.com
Sec-Ch-Ua: "(Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="99"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36
Sec-Ch-Ua-Arch: "x86"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Full-Version: "99.0.4844.51"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform-Version: "10.0.0"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Bitness: "64"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Model: 
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
X-Client-Data: CJDnygE=
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Referer: https://www.google.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

</request>
    <status>204</status>
    <responselength>781</responselength>
    <mimetype />
    <response base64="false">HTTP/2 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
Bfcache-Opt-In: unload
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 17:59:10 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 0
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2022-03-14-17; expires=Wed, 13-Apr-2022 17:59:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; SameSite=none
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

</response>
    <comment />
  </item>
</items>
```

Update: have continued messing with the code for the past couple days with still no luck. Any and all thoughts welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply save output to a *single* dictionary variable of many items. Because your text split requires multiple steps, consider a defined method.

```py
# DEFINED METHOD TO SPLIT RESPONSE BY LINE BREAKS
def split_text(resp): 
    responses = resp.split("\n")
    index = responses.index('') 
    indexed = responses[:index]

    return indexed

# PARSE XML FILE
doc = ET.fromstring(new)

# RETRIEVE ITEM NODES WITH DICTIONARY COMPREHENSION
website_items = {
    item.find("url").text: split_text(item.find("response").text)
    for item in doc.findall(".//item")
}

# REVIEW SAVED DATA WITH URLS AS KEYS
website_items["https://www.youtube.com/sw.js_data"]
website_items["https://www.google.com/client_204?&amp;atyp=i&amp;biw=1440&amp;bih=849&amp;dpr=1.5&amp;ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ"]
```

Comment: love how clean this looks, looks like a much better way of going about what I'm attempting to do. The first two blocks run without issues but when I try to run the third block (website_items) I get the following error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Thanks! Great to hear. I adjusted code to fix that error.

Comment: works now - thank you! One last question for you, if I wanted to have this script run through each website_item to check if certain headers are missing would that just be a for loop? If possible, I would like it to print results for each website_item (no matter how many) where it says website1: nothing missing , website2: missing xxx header, website3: nothing missing. Any ideas on how I would effectively do that?

Comment: Yes, loop through this dictionary and iterate through its element and specify a string search condition of what to look for in extracted XML text. Then print the dictionary key and whatever result (missing vs nothing). Give it a try and ask a new question if needed.

Comment: thanks so much - appreciate the help!